# Will ARC have trouble managing Objective C objects returned from a C-style function

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm having some troubles finding an answer to this in the documentation, but maybe you guys are better at it!

I have created a `.h` file called Types.h where I define an NS_ENUM:

```
#ifndef Types_h
#define Types_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, DataType) {
    TYPE_STRING,
    TYPE_NUMBER,
    TYPE_BOOLEAN,
    TYPE_NULL,
    TYPE_UNDEFINED
};

NSString *dataTypeString (DataType dt);

#endif
```

The C-style method definition is implemented in the `.m` file:

```
#import "Types.h"

// Ugly but convenient name.
NSString *dataTypeString (DataType dt) {
    switch(dt) {
        case TYPE_STRING:   return @"TYPE_STRING";
        case TYPE_NUMBER:   return @"TYPE_NUMBER";
        case TYPE_BOOLEAN:  return @"TYPE_BOOLEAN";
        case TYPE_NULL:     return @"TYPE_NULL";
        case TYPE_UNDEFINED:return @"TYPE_UNDEFINED";
    }
}
```

It's purpose is to return the String representation of my frequently used NS_ENUM for debug purposes.

However, I want to verify that this type of behaviour works with ARC. I.e allocing and returning an Objective-C object from a C-style method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work with ARC. `dataTypeString` returns Objective-C string literal. It doesn't matter how return objects, ARC or without-ARC. The retainCount of string literal is always 1 (or -1, whatever it means constant, infinite).

Also you can use C macro to get Objective-C string literal from enum like this.

```
@import Foundation;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, DataType) {
    TYPE_STRING,
    TYPE_NUMBER,
    TYPE_BOOLEAN,
    TYPE_NULL,
    TYPE_UNDEFINED
};

#define STRINGIFY(x) @#x

int main()
{
    NSLog(@"%ld", TYPE_BOOLEAN);
    NSLog(@"%@", STRINGIFY(TYPE_BOOLEAN));
    NSLog(@"%p", STRINGIFY(TYPE_BOOLEAN));
    NSLog(@"%p", STRINGIFY(TYPE_BOOLEAN));
    return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
2
TYPE_BOOLEAN
0x107b51058
0x107b51058   // The same address because the same string literal exists just only one.
```

Comment: *It does work with ARC.* is correct and it doesn't matter of the string is a string literal.  This answer is, effectively, "it works by coincidence".  A better answer would point out that returning objects from C functions under ARC works just like returning objects from methods (which shouldn't be a surprise as a method is nothing more than a C function with two pre-defined arguments).   Also, the retainCount verbiage is wrong and implying that it is meaningful isn't useful, either.